# How to uninstall Python3 from ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: python3

I've seen the previous answers that are already here about how to uninstall python, but it talks about ubuntu 16.04, so i'm asking if there is a way to definitely delete python from ubuntu 18.04 cause i want to install anaconda, and i don't wanna merge things.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean with "i don't wanna merge things". The conda installation instructions explicitly says "You do not need to uninstall other Python installations or packages in order to use conda. Even if you already have a system Python, another Python installation from a source such as the macOS Homebrew package manager and globally installed packages from pip such as pandas and NumPy, you do not need to uninstall, remove, or change any of them before using conda.". Since python3 is a quite vital core package, removing it will not be easy (if even possible).

Comment: It's a Bad Idea that can only end in tears. Don't do it. Uninstalling the specific version of Python3 that is installed with Ubuntu will break your system quite horribly.